# Struct unpack endianness issue: bad char in struct format

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I am reading a binary file into a stream of 4-byte unsigned integers.

```
if filename:
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as file:
        fileData = file.read()
        u32Data = struct.unpack('I' * (len(fileData )//4), fileData )
```

The default endianness on my machine is little-endian. I changed the endianness to big-endian in last line of code above:

```
u32Data = struct.unpack('>I' * (len(fileData )//4), fileData )
```

However I get following error when I change the last line from little to big endian:

```
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your format string ends up as `'>I>I>I>I>I>I...'` which is invalid, `>` is only allowed as very first letter in your format string. Use

```
u32Data = struct.unpack('>' + ('I' * (len(fileData )//4)), fileData )
```

Comment: Also works without parenthesis: u32Data = struct.unpack('>' + 'I' * (len(fileData )//4), fileData )